# Haproxy ssl termination for LDAP

Tags: ssl, ldap, haproxy

I would like to ask you for any kind of 
example that illustrates SSL termination for LDAP and Haproxy (636 on frontent and 389 on backend).

The configuration should look like haproxy:

-haproxy frontend that listens to 636 port

-haproxy backend that receives decrypted traffic from frontend

The examples for 389->389 and 636->636 are present on the Internet:

https://support.snapt.net/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004377189-Configuring-LDAP-haproxy-cfg

However I could not find any samples that illustrate on how to configure 
LDAP 636->389 ssl termination with Haproxy

You can find a sample that did not work in my environment below:

```
frontend ldap-636
bind 172.16.94.12:636 ssl crt /vagrant/cert_haproxy.pem no-sslv3 no-tlsv10 ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
mode tcp
option socket-stats
option tcplog
option tcpka
default_backend ldap-389-origin

backend ldap-389-origin
server freeipa.yeskela.tk 172.16.94.11:389 check fall 3 rise 5 inter 5000
mode tcp
balance leastconn
stick-table type ip size 200k expire 30m
timeout server 12s
timeout client 10s
timeout connect 10s
option tcpka
option tcp-check
tcp-check connect port 389
tcp-check send-binary 300c0201 # LDAP bind request "<ROOT>" simple
tcp-check send-binary 01 # message ID
tcp-check send-binary 6007 # protocol Op
tcp-check send-binary 0201 # bind request
tcp-check send-binary 03 # LDAP v3
tcp-check send-binary 04008000 # name, simple authentication
tcp-check expect binary 0a0100 # bind response + result code: success
tcp-check send-binary 30050201034200 # unbind request
```

Haproxy with the configuration that implements frontend-backend 389-389
works fine,
however as soon as I apply the snippet above ldapsearch request returns an error:

```
ldapsearch -h lb.yeskela.tk -p 636 -x -D "uid=admin,ou=people,o=ipaca" -W -b "" -s base
Enter LDAP Password: 
ldap_result: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The mode you are using is a [simple TCP pass-through](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/the-four-essential-sections-of-an-haproxy-configuration/#mode) -- since TCP mode, unlike HTTP mode, is not protocol aware, I do not believe it is possible to perform SSL off-loading as you desire.

Comment: Is it correct that such approach is not doable with Haproxy and LDAP at all? I mean that the only solution with Haproxy would be to proxy 389 to 389 port and 636 to 636 port? 
Thanks again for your help.

Comment: It's not the ports that need to match but the protocol. I can use HAProxy to take clear-text LDAP requests on 389/tcp and forward them over to the clear-text LDAP server that is configured on 1389/tcp. You cannot forward encrypted LDAP traffic on 636/tcp to an unencrypted LDAP server. On 389/tcp or even if you configured that LDAP server to 'speak' clear-text LDAP on 636/tcp

Comment: Actually, his config is not using TCP passthrough as can be noted by the "ssl" keyword in bind config. The "ssl" imply ssl termination and ldaps to ldap is perfectly doable by haproxy.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is your `ldapsearch` options. For ldaps  to work, you need to use `-H ldaps://host:port` or simply `ldaps://host` if using default ldaps port (636). Note that `-h` and `-p` are deprecated in favor of `-H`.

Also note that most clients (ldapsearch included) check if the `host` part (above) match the CN (subject common name) or SAN (Subject Alternative Name) of the certificate.